# How to clear search history at Hotmail?

Tags: search, outlook.com

I have an email account on hotmail.com. I have searched a few words, using the left search bar, to find something in my emails. However, when I click on the search bar now, I still see those words, which I've searched recently.

How can I remove those recently searched words from the search bar?

[image: Hotmail search bar]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to only store the last 5. If there is one that annoys you, you can just do new searches until it drops off.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays its stored in the user account on the server side, so it's not possible to delete it - only rewrite it. This is the official statement:

> As of the moment, removing auto-complete feature on **Search Mail and People** is not yet available.

**[https://answers.microsoft.com/1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osearch/search-history-in-outlookcom-mail/3c24c557-c894-4297-8515-3f65d14f3209)

[https://answers.microsoft.com/2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/opersonalization-oother/how-to-delete-search-history-entries-in-new/5227d392-2746-4740-9adb-e1f6fbfec31c)**

[image]

In old days it was stored locally, so you would need to do:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

- or to visit **https://outlook.live.com/mail/options/general/export/**
- and click on the **<kbd>Delete history</kbd>** button